# Converting text to a "light board"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I need your advise. It's about this app:

[LEDit Free](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/ledit-free/id369599161?mt=8)

**EDIT:** The referenced app displays text in the way a lighted board would, as a series of illuminated dots.

Basically you can insert your text and it will be scrolled through the screen. You can try it youself, there's a light version

But how did they manage to put the individual text exactly on the image with it's circles? I think it is very labour-intensive, isn't it?

Comment: Too localized. Please try and generalize your question.

Comment: Edited to be a bit more general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we used to do this with real LED displays, we just used bitmaps. So for example, the character H and A could be defined (in its simplest form) as arrays of booleans:

```
bool[] H = { 1,0,0,0,0,1,   bool[] A = { 0,0,1,1,0,0,
             1,0,0,0,0,1,                0,1,0,0,1,0,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,                0,1,1,1,1,0,
             1,0,0,0,0,1,                1,0,0,0,0,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,1 }               1,0,0,0,0,1 }
```

Then for each character in the text it finds the right bitmap in the table and turns on the right LEDs, or in this case it switches the right images.

Comment: So I think it's very complicated. Would someone be interested in doing this for me and get paid?

Would be nice

Comment: Did you do this manually for each character, or how did you do this. Thanks :)

Comment: We first created an array of all characters like shown above, call it a bitmap font if you'd like. We then iterated over each character and turned on the right LED's.

Comment: Ah, misunderstanding. I recall we made a helper tool to easily create bitmap fonts. It was basically just a grid of checkboxes that generated the right arrays corresponding to the checked boxes.

Comment: I really have no idea. I imagine it would be the alphabet plus some fun bitmap art added.

Answer (score 2):

While I suspect they probably use the mechanism @Sietse van der Molen suggests (since it is very straightforward), there are other, more general ways to do this.

One way is to create a small black-and-white bitmap image with the resolution of your light board. Then you draw your text using whatever font you like and read the bitmap to determine which pixels are turned on.